# How to make sure that my windows system is connected to network

Tags: java, windows, networking, network-programming, ping

I am creating a utility that also has a list of few ip addresses that are attached to my network.

I need to create a module that keeps refreshing that list so that only alive IP's are present in that list. 
I have thought of achieving this by using PING on each of the IP's and remove non responsive ones.

Problem is that I dont want to delete IP's when my System itself is not connected to network as in that case all of the IP's will get deleted for obvious reasons.

How can I be sure that my system is connected to some network?
I am using Java. 
I have tried looking over other questions but could not find anything relevant.

[EDIT1]
IP list is manually added set,and server has several more IP's which I dont need to care about.So I cant do a lookup in entire server as suggested by @Hoijf below. Also the IP's change consistently, thats why I need to keep my list updated so that we can replace non responsive servers/IP.

Comment: Look around in JDK if there are APIs to enumerate all local network interfaces or IP addresses. They exist on OS side, but I don't know about Java. If they exist, look there if the machine still has the expected IP address assigned and if the status of the adapter is still UP.

Comment: Another approach is to query the information through one of the commandline tools. On windows e.g. `ipconfig`. You can start it as a subprocess. Parse the relevant information and see if your network adapter is still connected and the IP address assigned. However that might be more overhead than a direct Java/OS API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is that I dont want to delete IP's when my System itself is
>   not connected to network as in that case all of the IP's will get
>   deleted for obvious reasons.

This is a typical network isolation problem. You should consider cases where your LAN is still up (ipconfig would show NIC's status as UP), but, you've lost internet connectivity (at some upstream router). As a solution, you could consider pinging a reference IP/host that is always supposed to be up.
So, you should create a policy in your program to ping this reference host to check if you should remove the host from your active list.

Comment: Network Isolation problem seems legit term for this scenario. I have to figure some guaranteed IP and use it as reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan the network and save the IPs which are active.
2. Store the IPs in an array and iterate over this array until the user chooses to stop or refresh (back to step 1).
3. Display the status of each IP.

   ```
   public class temp
   {
   static ArrayList<InetAddress> history = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();
   static Timer timer;
   static InetAddress add;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       int timeout = 25;
       timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           for(InetAddress ii : history)
           {
               try
               {
                   System.out.println(ii+" >> "+ii.isReachable(timeout));
               } catch (IOException e1){System.out.println(ii+" >>                          Failed");}
           }
       }
   });
   Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {
           while(true)
           {
               try
               {
                   history.add(InetAddress.getByName(br.readLine()));
               } catch (UnknownHostException e)
               {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e)
               {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
       });
       t.start();
       timer.start();
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks for revert.
Problem is that if connected, my network will have 1000+ systems and i need to care only about the already existing IP's which were initially added manually to the list. This is so because we get only specific IP's (IP to virtual servers) to use at a time and those virtual servers often get removed. This is an absurd arrangement but fits well in our organization for some specific requirement. My question probably is not clear with that requirement, updating.

Comment: Ok then have a user input method for an ip. You can then save the IP in a file and reload it if necessary later on. Scanning the network isn't necessary, the principles are the same.

Comment: #hoijf all you suggested is correct but just wont fit in my particular use case. Anyways as suggested by @sanjayk79 seems I need to figure out some IP that is guaranteed to be up all time, still a risky case as our network is really dynamic.